# How to remove product page link? woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I want to remove just single product link from product picture. I am trying to fix one-page checkout. There should be only checkout link on this page. so this is on quickview.

https://ordermenu.ivasushibistro.com/

I tried out those links but no result

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005275/remove-linkurl-to-image-for-woocommerce-products

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-disable-lightbox-and-hyperlink-on-product-images
```

also those css codes

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery__image {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.product-image-link {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Give more information on what problem you are facing when you try to remove it.

Comment: when you click the product image it is going to product page. i want to remove this link from image.

Comment: Can you add to the question about what all things you tried? Also, have you looked at https://community.getbeans.io/discussion/removing-the-html-image-link-from-woocommerce-single-product/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005275/remove-linkurl-to-image-for-woocommerce-products

Comment: i tried already all function codes but did not work also could not a way with css

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“i tried already all function codes”_ is not the kind of information we can use as basis to help you here to begin with. You need to show us what you tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it.

Comment: I tried opening your link and I see it's already without the link to the single product, only the add to cart button is working. So, you solved it? Or maybe you was watching the cached version of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want the image to don't be clickable and you're okay with having the URL as public, you can add the following CSS:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .top-product-section > p:first-child a.product-category {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will make the image not clickable but keep the button clickable